# Strategies on showing if a sequence of functions do not have a converging subsequence

Tags: metric-spaces, soft-question

I can recall that from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436120/real-analysis-a-sequence-that-has-no-convergent-subsequence) about 'the sequence $(a_n)$ has no converging subsequence if and only if $|a_n|$ tends to infinity'. Can I extend this lemma into the sequence of functions and replaces the modulus function with a norm function? Would the result still hold?

Also are there other strategies to show a sequence of functions do not have a converging subsequence?

Comment: What "norm function"?

Answer (score 0):

The [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) tells us that any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence. This does not hold for metric spaces in general, and fails in most function spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that the question you're asking above is asking "can I replace the absolute value in the above statement with a modulus without losing the result?" Well the main problem with your question is that modulus takes two arguments, absolute value only takes one. And with any finite modulus (say, $M$), then your new sequence becomes $(a_n \mod M)$, which is obviously bounded and thus convergent by Bolzano-Weierstrass:
$$
(a_n\mod M)\subseteq[0,M)\subset [0,\infty)
$$
$$
\Downarrow 
$$
$$
a_{n_k}\in (a_n\mod M ), a_{n_k}\rightarrow a \text{ for some }a\in[0,M]
$$
As for the second half of this question, a very useful theorem for you would be the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, which states: *any bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence.*

Comment: I believe OP intends to replace the modulus function, $|x|$, with a norm, $||x||_{\text{something}}$.  I don't believe he intends to work modulo some  modulus, $M$.