# An example of a sequence .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to know the example of a sequence $x_n$ such that there is no convergent subsequence but $|x_n|$ converges.

My attempt:I think there will be no such sequence as if $\lim(|x_n|)$ is not $\infty$ then that would mean that $|x_k|<M $ for $k \ge N$ .Hence the sequence $x_n$ will be bounded so by bolzano weistrass it will have a  convergent subsequence.

Comment: This seems correct to me. There was a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436120/real-analysis-a-sequence-that-has-no-convergent-subsequence

Comment: Hint:  Consider the subsequence of only non-negative terms (or the subsequence of only non-positive terms).  Those terms are all $x_{i_k} = |x_{i_k}|$ so this is a subsequence of a converging sequence.

Comment: Your approach is correct.